# How to display all categories and their products on a single page in magento

Tags: magento

I wanted to display all categories ( with detail like name. description etc..) and their products ( with name, price,add to cart option etc..) on a single page in magento.

Please suggest, how this can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,

Comment: This question is not specific enough. What problems do you encounter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rootCategoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootCategoryId);

// get all sub categories of the root category
$subCategory = $category->getChildrenCategories();

// display parent category of the current category
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
echo $this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategory()->getName() ;

/* another sample */

$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

// display sub-category of current category
if ($currentCategory->getParentId() == Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId())
{
   // current category top-level category
   $rootCategory = $currentCategory;
}

else {  
// current category sub category of top-level category
$rootCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCategory->getParentId());
}  

$subCategory = explode(',', $rootCategory->getChildren());
foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
{
   $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

   // get status of category
   if($categories ->getIsActive())
   {
      echo '<a href="'.$categories->getURL().'">'.$categories->getName().'</a>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all products :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName() . "<br />";
}
```

[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/5259/) where it is copied from

and to get all the categories :

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

[link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-list-of-all-categories/) copied from